# Android application is installing 2 times in device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am getting multiple applications(with the same name) while installing this application, if I uninstall one other one gets deleted, in the beginning, the count was three but after making changes the count is two, now I want only single app ....how do ideal with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mypc.panjabisamajapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GirlsBoys">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegistrationForm" />
    <activity android:name=".UploadPhoto" />
    <activity android:name=".PopupOccupation" />
    <activity android:name=".ContactDetailsForm" />
    <activity android:name=".ParticularsForm" />
    <activity android:name=".UserProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayCardResult" />
    <activity android:name=".ZoomImage" />
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.mypc.panjabisamajapp.MailBox"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ChatWindow" />
    <activity android:name=".EditPProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".UpdateDetails">
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />


</application>
```

Comment: What is the name of other application? Put merged manifest of your application module.

Comment: it is creating with the similar name

Comment: Do you have multiple variants? maybe you are installing all of them

Comment: unique application id is in app/build.gradle file, not manifest file.

Comment: i am not getting your point ,please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app names are the same the reason can be using multiple launcher intent in your manifest file. Check your merged manifest file instead of application manifest file.

Comment: after removing another intent filter i got this - "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
"

Comment: Update your question with merged manifest content so I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

i think u must have used this intent filter  twice in multiple activities.check your manifest file

Comment: no i have added only one intent-filter ,i have added my manifest please check it

Comment: please remove this activity and  run ur app.     <activity android:name="com.example.mypc.panjabisamajapp.MailBox"></activity>

Comment: still it is creating 2 times